# Azure Storage Calculation of Blob Container Size

Tags: azure-storage

Below i have function with an external which calculate blob container size

```
function getBlobContainerSize(container, callback) {
    storageClient.listBlobsSegmented(container, null, null, function(error, result) {
        var length=0,counter=result.entries.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entries.length; i++) {
            getBlobSize(container, result.entries[i].name, function(size){
                length+=size;
                if(--counter===0) callback(length);
            });
        };
    });
}
function getBlobSize(container, blob, callback){
    storageClient.getBlobProperties(container, blob, function(err, result, response) {
        if(result==null) callback(0);
        else callback(parseInt(result.contentLength));
    }); 
}
```

And the result is for an specific container 20907510, and in the Azure Storage Explorer i see 84.03M. Correct me if i am wrong but this two is different by 64mb, Azure Storage Explorer show much more mb in compare with my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're using standard storage, the method you're using to calculate the size of container, may not be the size which Azure Storage bills you for. For page and block blobs in standard storage, Azure storage bills for the data stored. More detailed information can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx

Your method will give you the sum of content lengths of all the blobs in your container. Azure-Storage might still be billing you for less.

Comment: Hmm, Azure Storage Explorer show me how much they are billing?

Comment: I don't think so. 
Refer to the blog I shared earlier, follow the formula\steps to calculate the size. It should be fairly easy to get a ball park number, if you're using block blobs and no snapshots.

Page blobs and snapshots could be tricky, because Azure Storage will not bill for empty page ranges, and any data twice.... and you will have to keep track of such pages to be able to predict the actual size correctly.